# Xcode Swift initial view incorrectly sized

Tags: xcode, swift

When my app starts, the view looks like this:

[image]

Then when I change views using this code:

```
let skView = self.view! as SKView
var scene: TitleScene!
scene = TitleScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
skView.presentScene(scene, transition: transition)
```

And then change back to the initial screen again using the above technique, the screen looks like this:

[image]

Why is it zoomed out? How can I make the sizing remain consistent across all views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this line in the viewDidLoad method:

```
self.size = view.bounds.size
```

Comment: This is correct. I actually asked a similar question more recently with the same answer, however I just forgot about this one...